# Create a attribute dynamically

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm writing an xsl script in which I need to create the attribute dynamically.

Here is my sample code.

```
 <Table BORDERLINESTYLE="solid" BOTTOMMARGIN="12" NOTEGROUPSPACING="single" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="504"></Table>
```

Here `BORDERLINESTYLE` may or may not be available to all `Table` tags. and I want the output to be something like this.

```
<table style="border-style:solid; border-margin:12px; width:504px"></table>
```

Here are 2 things that I've tried.

**1. Creating attributes**

```
 <table>
    <xsl:if test="./@BORDERLINESTYLE">
        <xsl:attribute name="border" select="'1px solid'"/>
    </xsl:if>
    
     <xsl:if test="./@WIDTH">
        <xsl:attribute name="width" select="concat(./@WIDTH, 'px')"/>
    </xsl:if>
    
     <xsl:if test="./@BOTTOMMARGIN">
        <xsl:attribute name="border" select="'1px solid'"/>
    </xsl:if>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </table>
```

the output that I get is as below.

```
<table border="1px solid" width="504px">
```

**2. Inline adding**

```
<table style="width:{current()/@WIDTH,'px'}; border:{./@BORDERLINESTYLE}; margin-bottom: {./@BOTTOMMARGIN, 'px'}; margin-top:{./@TOPMARGIN, 'px'}; "></table>
```

and the output is as below with some blank values like `margin-top`

```
<table style="width:504 px; border:solid; margin-bottom: 12 px; margin-top:px; ">
```

How can I add styles to `style` based on the attributes provided in the XML?

I'm using XSLT2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
  <xsl:if test="@BORDERLINESTYLE|@WIDTH|@BOTTOMMARGIN|@TOPMARGIN">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
      <xsl:if test="@BORDERLINESTYLE">
        <xsl:text>border:1px solid;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@WIDTH">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('width:',@WIDTH, 'px;')"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@BOTTOMMARGIN">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('margin-bottom:',@BOTTOMMARGIN, 'px;')"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="@TOPMARGIN">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('margin-top:',@TOPMARGIN, 'px;')"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
```

And depending on the business rules for mapping those source-attributes to style attributes change the code accordingly.

Btw.: `./@` is the same as `@`

Answer (score 0):

Use if else Function

For Example

```
margin-top: {if(//@TOPMARGIN!=0) then {./@TOPMARGIN, 'px'} else '12px'}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create the attribute dynamically.

Actually, you want to *populate* the attribute dynamically - which could be done by applying a template to each input attribute you want to use:

```
<xsl:template match="Table">
    <table>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@BORDERLINESTYLE | @BOTTOMMARGIN | @WIDTH"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@BORDERLINESTYLE">
    <xsl:text>border-style:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@BOTTOMMARGIN">
    <xsl:text>border-margin:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>px; </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@WIDTH">
    <xsl:text>width:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```